# Font are not displayed in Idea

Tags: linux, fonts, intellij-idea

After updating jrk7-openjdk and jre7-openjdk fonts don't displaying from the Idea. Reinstalling the packages openjdk and idea didn't help.

uname -a:
Linux ftp27host 3.14.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jun 8 10:08:38 CEST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[image: Main]

[image: Settings]

Comment: Try copy ttf fonts into JDK_HOME/jre/lib/fonts

Comment: @bedna There are not have JDK_HOME, but there are JAVA_HOME. But moving font does not help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks, user3745346. I had the same problem with Idea ultimate under ArchLinux. Fixed by changing line

`-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd`

to

`-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on`

in the IDEA_HOME/bin/idea64.vmoptions

Comment: Thank you so much. You safe my arch :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with phpstorm (it's based on idea). I've found a solution by adding:

> export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on'

to my /usr/bin/phpstorm.sh

The file is now:

```
#!/bin/sh
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on'
cd /usr/share/phpstorm/bin/
./phpstorm.sh "$@"
```

I think it will be the same with idea.